# How to create a bean after initialization?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to provide an easy way to access to some header values, so my idea is:

```
@Autowired
private MyContext ctx;
```

problem is that I add infos in a filter at runtime, so I cannot set data inside:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    servletRequest.getHeader(...)
```

I found this solution: I save data inside of a servlet attribute and the class just become a wrapper for that:

```
@Component
public class MyContext{
    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;
public DTO getDto(){
        return (DTO)request.getAttribute("dto");
 }
```

It works but I don't like that, in my debug, I cannot directly see the DTO object. 
So, isn't there a way to create a bean after spring initialization?

Comment: Please provide more details on what is the requirement here ? Have you tried [`@RequestHeader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestHeader.html) if the need is to get header values ? And why you need to create a bean after spring initialization to get header values ?

Comment: You can create component manually and register as singleton : `applicationContext.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("simplebean", new SimpleBean());`

Answer (score 0):

i didn't get your question totally but i think so init method can help you. If you want some operation after bean creation just add those operation in init method and add the init method in bean creation configuration.

```
<bean name="bean" class="Bean" init-method="init"/>
```